# How to find google map anchor point of a svg path?

Tags: google-maps, svg, google-maps-markers

The problem is about google map marker icons. If i use default icon the position of icon is not changing but if i use a svg,the position of marker diverging.I want to use new google map anchor point for fix this problem but i dont know how i find the anchor point of my svg.Can anyone tell me doing that fix the problem or how i find anchor point of svg.The path is below.

path: "M125 410 c-56 -72 -111 -176 -120 -224 -7 -36 11 -83 49 -124 76 -85 223 -67 270 31 28 60 29 88 6 150 -19 51 -122 205 -148 221 -6 3 -32 -21 -57 -54z m110 -175 c35 -34 33 -78 -4 -116 -35 -35 -71 -37 -105 -7 -40 35 -43 78 -11 116 34 41 84 44 120 7z",

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/symbols#properties)

> anchor sets the position of the symbol relative to the marker or polyline. The coordinates of the symbol's path are translated left and up by the anchor's x and y coordinates respectively. **By default, a symbol is anchored at (0, 0). The position is expressed in the same coordinate system as the symbol's path.**)

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u74yc6ry/2/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var geocoder;
var map;

function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: map.getCenter(),
    icon: {
      path: 'M125 410 c-56 -72 -111 -176 -120 -224 -7 -36 11 -83 49 -124 76 -85 223 -67 270 31 28 60 29 88 6 150 -19 51 -122 205 -148 221 -6 3 -32 -21 -57 -54z m110 -175 c35 -34 33 -78 -4 -116 -35 -35 -71 -37 -105 -7 -40 35 -43 78 -11 116 34 41 84 44 120 7z',
      fillColor: "blue",
      fillOpacity: 0.8,
      scale: 0.1,
      strokeColor: 'blue',
      strokeWeight: 1,
      anchor: new google.maps.Point(185, 500)

    }
  });
  var point = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: map.getCenter(),
    icon: {
      url: "https://maps.gstatic.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/markers2/measle.png",
      size: new google.maps.Size(7, 7),
      anchor: new google.maps.Point(3.5, 3.5)
    }
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<div id="map_canvas" style="width:750px; height:450px; border: 2px solid #3872ac;"></div>
```