# adjusting google Map lat-long with a google.Point()

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, latitude-longitude

so i have a custom svg marker, so i needed to give it an anchor of 
        `anchor: new google.maps.Point(100, 100)`.  from what i can see this causes my marker to be slightly off from where it should be.   how can i correct this, for instance i was thinking something like

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    anchor:google.maps.Point(sizeX , sizeY ),
    position: myLatLng- new google.maps.Point(sizeX, sizeY),
 });
```

but obviously this doesnt work because latlng and Points are different formats.  so any idea on how to get around this?   how can i convert google.Points into something i can do latLong Operations on

Comment: there is an  `anchor`-property for a  google.maps.Icon/google.maps.Symbol which may be set.  https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=en&csw=1#Symbol

Comment: I don't understand because you need this: why you don't place your custom marker to position?

Comment: so bascally, i placed the marker on the map at myLatLng,  because it is a custom svg i had to give it the anchor of the middle of my svg,  those are the values that is in sizeX and sizeY.   so while it is anchored it the middle, it seems to still place the marker at(0,0) instead of (sizeX, sizeY).   so basically what im getting at, is that if i say position:latLng, then my map anchor doesnt correspond with my latLong, so its always off

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue, including an example of your custome SVG icon.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find google map anchor point of a svg path?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32481984/how-to-find-google-map-anchor-point-of-a-svg-path)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rotating symbols while keeping track of the anchor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12472637/rotating-symbols-while-keeping-track-of-the-anchor)